# Stratified KFold CV Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am designing a classfier for multi class problem with imbalance dataset. For this problem I decided to oversmaple the minority classes using `SMOTE` and for the algorithm, I decided to use `Logistic Regression`, even though later I will use different model to compare the preformance. I did the preprocessing data, split the dataset into traing and test set, and only oversample the training set. Then from that I normalize both training set and test set using `MinMaxScaler()`. Using the holdout set, my model have decent scores shown below:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0      0.991     0.883     0.934     54694
           1      0.308     0.834     0.450      3396
           2      0.718     0.978     0.828       416

    accuracy                          0.881     58506
   macro avg      0.672     0.898     0.737     58506
weighted avg      0.949     0.881     0.905     58506
```

I decided to use `StratifiedKFold` to see the average performance of my model. The result is way lower than what I was expected. Here's the result on 1 of the fold. the other fold also yield similar score as well:

```
Classification Report on test set:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.03      0.05     60928
           1       0.03      0.03      0.03      3621
           2       0.01      0.96      0.01       457

    accuracy                           0.03     65006
   macro avg       0.35      0.34      0.03     65006
weighted avg       0.94      0.03      0.05     65006
```

And here's my stratified Kfold implementation:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
scalerCC = MinMaxScaler()
smote = SMOTE(random_state=42)


for train_index, test_index in tqdm(skf.split(x, y), total=skf.get_n_splits()):
    x_train_fold, x_test_fold = x.iloc[train_index], x.iloc[test_index]
    y_train_fold, y_test_fold = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    
    # resample training set
    x_train_fold_resampled, y_train_fold_resampled = smote.fit_resample(x_train_fold, y_train_fold)
    
    # normalize both training and test set
    x_train_scaled = scalerCC.fit_transform(x_train_fold_resampled) 

    x_test_scaled = scalerCC.transform(x_test_fold)
    
    # Train the model with training set
    logreg.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train_fold_resampled)
    
    train_pred = logreg.predict(x_train_scaled)
    
    train_report = classification_report(y_train_fold_resampled, train_pred)
    print(f'Classification Report on training set:\n{train_report}')
    
    #test the model
    y_pred_fold = logreg.predict(x_test_fold)
    
    #print the report
    report = classification_report(y_test_fold, y_pred_fold)
    print(f'Classification Report on test set:\n{report}')
    
    #print the confusion matrix
    logreg_cm = confusion_matrix(y_test_fold,y_pred_fold)
    disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = logreg_cm)
    disp.plot()
```

I thought this is happening beacuse I was oversmapling the training set. I tried to undersampling, and left the dataset as it is but added `class_weight='balanced'` but it still yield the same low metric scores than using the holdout set method. I also tried to change the number of fold, but it didnt change the the scores much. Am I doing something wrong on my Stratified Kfold CV implementation? Can someone point it to me and tell me what should be changed